# MS "VCard" french specials chars

Tags: c#, asp.net, vcf-vcard

I'm trying to create VCard on the fly for a site. I simply open a "real" VCard once create with Outlook with Notepad++ and saw what I need into it to create one on the fly. Everything works fine and I'm able to add anything I need, where I need. Instead one point :

- All french caracters such as É, À, Ê, Ç, etc showing like : Simon Dugr**Ã©**.

I've add everything suggested by the Outlook created one who's proposing to add : "CHARSET=Windows-1252:" in front of my string entry (also tryied ISO-8859-1, UTF8, UTF7, UTF-8, UTF-7) and none of those are working.

Any suggestion?

**EDIT (After Alexandre C.'s answer)**
Here is the VCard source. *Please note that the source shows it correctly, but when I open it with Outlook, I still have the accent problem* :

> BEGIN:VCARD
>   VERSION:2.1
>   N;LANGUAGE=fr-ca;CHARSET=UTF-8:Dugré;Simon
>   ORG;CHARSET=utf-8:CompanyNameéàêâç
>   TEL;WORK;VOICE:5555555555
>   X-MS-OL-DEFAULT-POSTAL-ADDRESS:0
>   EMAIL;PREF;INTERNET:hello@world.com
>   X-MS-OL-DESIGN;CHARSET=utf-8:[VCard HTML Format]
>   REV:20110404T135700
>   END:VCARD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should write `CHARSET=utf-8` and not `CHARSET=UTF-8`.

**vCard** specs suggest that character set should be case independent, but Outlook does not care.

Comment: It is exactly what helped me. I'd also add: `;CHARSET=utf-8` has to be added in every row that can contain accents.

Comment: You saved my day. Outlook is funny

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **good** line:

```
currentPage.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0} {1}.vcf", this.FirstName, this.LastName));
currentPage.Response.ContentType = "text/x-vcard";
currentPage.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"); // THIS LINE
currentPage.Response.Write(content);
currentPage.Response.End();
```

Instead of :

```
currentPage.Response.Charset = "ISO-8859-1";
```

Comment: A question about this ; Is it ok to put "Default" ? Because, default, in this case, is default of the server. Is it any possible "conflict" with user when this one gonna open it on his computer?

Comment: You should check what the default is on your machine.  If the default changes it may break for you.

Comment: Thanks Darryl. I've changed my answer.

Comment: This works for Latin 1, but it is not UTF-8 compatible... Unless your answer was meant to say "UTF-8" as the Charset in the first block of code and "ISO-8859-1" in the second block?

Answer (score 0):

Try `utf8` or `utf-8` as the charset.

Comment: Ain't working ... still same. But when I look into the source, it shows it as "É" and not Ã©... realy weird

Comment: UFT8, UFT7, ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252 also include É or È, etc. But in this case, for un unkown reason, none of those seems to be working...

Comment: When you encode the text on your webserver are you sending it out as utf-8?

Comment: Here's my line ... content.AppendLine(string.Format("N;LANGUAGE=fr-ca;CHARSET=ISO-8859-1:{0};{1}", this.LastName, this.FirstName)); But, why do the VCard source still shows it as "É" and not "Ã©". And why the one created with Outlook, shows it as "É" in source and "É" when looking it with outlook?

Comment: Ã© is utf8. Period. It means the file is saved as utf8, so you need to act accordingly, or reencode the file (eg. with standard notepad), perhaps in iso8859-1 or 15.

Comment: You're right. Sorry Alex. I've got an idea now cuz Notepad++ encoding tabs shows it was in UTF-8 compartivly to the one created with Outlook which is in ANSI... I'll try to change my Page output Response to "Default" and I'll come back

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that works for me.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"  CodePage=1252 %>
<%
Response.Charset ="windows-1252";
Response.ContentType="text/x-vcard";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.vcf" );
 %>
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:;Dugré;Simon
FN:Simon Dugré
ORG:CompanyNameéàêâç
TEL;WORK;VOICE:5555555555
EMAIL;PREF;INTERNET:hello@world.com
REV:20110405T164322Z
END:VCARD
```

This loads correctly into Outlook 2003.

Comment: I've tryied to do the same as you said, and it do not work ... but I just saw "This loads correctly into Outlook 2003". May it be because I'm with Outlook 2007 ?

Comment: Did you try taking the code as is and putting it on your webserver as an aspx page?  If not give that a try and see what happens. 

The other thing I would do is create the contact in Outlook 2007 and save it as a vcard to see what the output looks like.

Comment: Thank Darryl. But also tryied! And it is the same, exact same VCard's "Source". Exept that with Notepad++, encoding seem to be different as @Alexander C says (sorry). It opens it as UTF-8. I will try anothing way to ouput my page response and I'll come back. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem with special characters (polish language). I am not sure if there's a problem with utf-8 encoding in Outlook or something else. After multiple approaches with utf-8:

`Response.ContentType = "text/x-vcard; charset=UTF-8";`

`Response.HeaderEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");`

`Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");`

`Response.Charset = "UTF-8";`

I decided to try Windows-1250 encoding, which (in my case) worked! After trying to remove unnecessary lines it turned out that the only line i need is:

`Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1250");`

I also recommend [vCard](http://www.thoughtproject.com/Libraries/vCard/) library which helped me a lot.